# Sentence-Wrap (property word-wrap)

Tags: css

I need to keep a sentence not wrapping when the width of the div is smaller than this sentence

```css
.ex1 {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  width: 25%;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
This is my sentence
</div>
```

The probleme is that properties `overflow-x:visible` or `word-wrap: normal` not working when the sentence contains spaces

Comment: You say _not wrapping_ - what do you mean?  Should the text disappear where the width is not enough? Should the `div` expand to fit the text?

Comment: white-space:nowrap ?

Comment: I mean my sentence not returning in other line whene the width of div not enough.

Comment: Thanks Afif white-space work

Comment: Add this line into style: **div{ white-space: nowrap; }**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `white-space` to control how white spaces are handled:

```css
.ex1 {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  width: 25%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
  This is my sentence
</div>
<div class="ex1">
  Line breaks are suppressed here
</div>
```

Comment: Add this line into style: **div{  white-space: nowrap;  }**

Comment: Thanks, white-space work

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely certain what you mean by *not wrapping*.

Either, the text could disappear at the end of the `div`:

```css
.ex1 {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  width: 25%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
This is my sentence
</div>
```

This is achieved by setting the `white-space` to `nowrap`, forcing the text to *not wrap*, and then hiding any overflow on the x-axis (`overflow-x: hidden`).

Or alternatively, the `div` could expand to fit the text:

```css
.ex1 {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  width: 25%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
This is my sentence
</div>
```

As above, using `no-wrap`, but allowing overflow by not hiding it.